# Surveymonkey API - General editing

Tags: surveymonkey

Can the API let me add or update questions and question answers.

For example say I have a multi option question.

What is your fav animal?
1. Cat
2. Dog

could I use the API to update a 3rd option of say Cow?

Cheers....

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot edit a survey via the API. That can only be done using SurveyMonkey's user interface.